# finding umvu estimator of parameter $\theta$

Tags: statistics

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are a random sample of uniform distribution on interval $(0,1)$. If 
$$
Z_i = \begin {cases} X_i & \text{w.p. }\theta, \\
-X_i & \text{w.p. }1-\theta,  \end {cases} \qquad 0<\theta<1
$$
and $P$ denote the number of pozitive $Z_i$, how can find umvu estimator of parameter $\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
Y_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }Z_i>0, \\  0 & \text{if }Z_i<0. \end{cases}
$$
Now show that the conditional distribution of $Z_i$ given $Y_i$ does not depend on $\theta$.  Therefore $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is sufficient for $\theta$.  And indeed, it's not hard to show the same is true of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i$.  So that is sufficient.  And that sum has a binomial distribution.  If you've done a similar problem for the binomial distribution, then you've got it.